# Mame and xfce4 virtual desktop,some interfences

Tags: xfce, virtual-desktop

Sometimes i like to play old coinops with MAME
on mame the default keys for play are

```
Directional keys

UP 
DOWN
LEFT
RIGHT
```

for movement
and
ctrl and left alt for fire button1 and 2
I like this and i don't want to change.
The problem is also xfce4 has the combination

```
left or right + left ctrl and left alt
```

for switch virtual desktop.
Of course when i play i use the key and...game disappear
and switch between desktop.
My question is: is possible to assign other keys
or temporary block virtual dekstop on xfce4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found must use "always on visible workspace"
In menu,is a workaround,probably a cli was better
but this work fine.